# On an Experience Manager website the UI loads but the component is not editable

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t

I am implementing experience manager on my DD4T Website.

I am able to edit Page metadata content but not Component content in Experience Manager. Below is the HTML rendering on my page:

```
<section class="main" role="main">
    <figure id="ball-box" class="widgetContainer">
          <!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:33-1690", "ComponentModified" : "2014-05-09T18:54:04", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:33-1863-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2014-07-25T09:15:42", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false} -->
          <h2><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Header[1]"} -->Component field text</h2>
          <h2><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Header[1]"} --> Component field text</h2>
          <div>
              <!-- Start Region: { "title": "Howm Page Widget", "allowedComponentTypes": [ {"schema": "tcm:2-76-8", "template": "tcm:33-1863-32"}, ], "minOccurs": 1 } -->
         </div>
    </figure>
</section>
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:33-1859-64","PageModified":"2014-07-29T08:33:49","PageTemplateID":"tcm:33-1860-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-07-29T06:44:37"} -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://cmsurl.com/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>;
```

Below is my siteedit_config setting:

```
<siteEdit enabled="true" style="SiteEdit2012" tridionHostUrl="http://cmsurl.com">
<contextPublications>
    <contextPublication id="33" pagePublication="33" componentPublication="4" publishPublication="33"/>
</contextPublications>
</siteEdit>
```

Can anyone suggest the probable area of issue?

Comment: Do you get any indication of XPM running properly - borders around component presentations, around fields, etc?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Nuno. I can edit metadata of my page and can verify the changes in CMS. I am not able to update the component content. Yes, I can see the component presentations, not around field.

Comment: Is there a lock icon in the CPs? What happens if you click inside it?

Comment: I can't see any lock in component presentation. When I click inside component presentation siteedit UI showing my component as a selected item but I am not able to edit that.

Comment: Is your field in the schema enabled for inline editing? (Checkbox called 'Enable for Inline Editing')

Comment: Yes Albert it is enabled. Isn't it a issue with region setting. Below is my region:
<regions>
   <schemas>
    <schema name="Home Page Widget" tcmUri="tcm:33-76-8" />
  </schemas>
  <templates>
    <template name="XPM HomePage Widget DD4T CT" tcmUri="tcm:33-1863-32"  />
  </templates>
 
  <region name="Howm Page Widget" id="HowmPageWidget">
    <allowedComponentTypes>
      <componentType schema="Home Page Widget" template="XPM HomePage Widget DD4T CT" />
    </allowedComponentTypes>
  </region>
</regions>

Comment: Can you update your question with the correct HTML? It seems like there are some tags missing...

Comment: @MukeshKumar Include the HTML elements wrapping the Component Presentation and post the markup *in the question*, not in a comment.

Comment: HTML updated in question.

Comment: Include the wrapping markup for your Component Presentation.

Comment: It is already included in the question. Isn't it what you want to see?

<!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:33-1690", "ComponentModified" : "2014-05-09T18:54:04", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:33-1863-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2014-07-25T09:15:42", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false} -->

Comment: There is no HTML element containing the Component Presentation? e.g `<div><!-- Start Comp... </h2></div>`?

Comment: Hi Ant,

I have updated the question with complete markup. Please have a look.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ant,

I can see the region in siteedit area is highlighting error as below:

A region in this page has fewer or more item than allowed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set your BluePrint Context settings in Tridion as well as in the site_edit_config.xml file? This can often cause the behaviour you describe.

Open the following menu

[image: BluePrint Context Menu location]

Then for each of your staging website publications, match the settings to those you have set in the site_edit_config.xml file.

[image: Settings]

Comment: I removed DD4T from the post and tags, as this was not related to it at all.

Comment: Not sure I agree there Nuno, the asker was in the context of DD4T and both question and answer mention the file site_edit_config.xml which is DD4T specific. I've made the same mistake myself and think others might too and will probably include "dd4t" in the search. Hence I've added the DD4T tag back in.