# Experience Manager component presentation is not editable

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t

Component presentation border on my page is showing it as non-editable. Content-Border is showing as gray. It was editable earlier. I have verified the html of page and found no change. Can anyone suggest what may be the cause of the issue? Markup of page is as below:

```
<section class="main" role="main">
    <figure id="ball-box" class="widgetContainer">


  <!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:33-1690", "ComponentModified" : "2014-07-30T16:49:20", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:33-1675-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2014-05-06T19:23:41", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false} -->

<figcaption id="homeWidget" class="homepage widget">
    <h2>
        <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Header[1]"} -->
        Component content 1
    </h2>
    <text>
        <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Description[1]"} -->
        component content 2
    </text>


        <a href="/Services/" class="learn-more"><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Link[1]/custom:LinkText[1]"} -->component content 3</a>

</figcaption>

    </figure>
</section>
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:33-1671-64","PageModified":"2014-07-25T17:35:32","PageTemplateID":"tcm:33-1673-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-04-23T15:03:59"} --><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://cmsurl/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>;
```

Comment: Maybe the component is checked out by someone else?

Comment: Hi Nuno,

I can see, component is not checked out in CMS. But, I can see lock while component presentation is rendering on the page in site edit UI. Actually, earlier have done other work too on this page which I now rolled back. But found that now my component is showing non-editable.

Please suggest..

Thanks.
Mukesh

Comment: It is possible that the component is localised at a lower publication and checked out there, hence the lock you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Nickoli, But the publication I am working on is the lowest one and I have verified that it is not localized or locked anywhere..

Comment: What does it say if you click on the padlock? Usually Experience Manager will try and offer an explanation.

Comment: Thanks Rob,

I have found that Blue print context was not correct inside CMS and that was the root cause of the issue..

Thanks.
Mukesh

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question you asked here? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/on-an-experience-manager-website-the-ui-loads-but-the-component-is-not-editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the answer of my question. Below is the steps I have analyzed and corrected to resolve the issue:

1. BluePrint context setting in CMS was not correct.
2. Although it was correct in my SiteEdit_config setting file.

I have corrected that and all are working now.

Below is little bit more explanation:

Actually, my component was ccraeted and coming from parent publication(suppose P) and was used in page of the child publication(suppose C). In my blueprint context setting, context for component was configured as C.

Earlier I was thinking that experience manager reading context setting from SiteEdit_config file, which was already correct. But later found that it is reading setting from blueprint context setting.

I have configured blueprint context for component as parent publication(P) and now everything started working.

I hope the issue and resolution is clear now..

Thanks. 
Mukesh

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you did to resolve the issue so someone else with a similar issue can be helped too :)

Comment: Hi jarnohenneman,

I have provided more detail around issue and it's resolution. I hope now it will be more understandable.

Comment: you are mentioning a `SiteEdit_config` settings file, I'm assuming that is the one from DD4T? When using DD4T you indeed have to make sure that both your DD4T configuration on your website and the XPM configuration in the CMS are both valid and matching.

Comment: +1 to Bart's comment, I tagged the question with DD4T. It's important to note that `SiteEdit_config` only applies for DD4T and the context isn't really an issue by itself. Though using a Parent Publication for Component context is typical, the real issue is either the mismatch in configuration or possibly one of the more typical reasons for locked items (no scope, no permission, item edited by someone else, workflow, etc).