# Not able to edit the component in Experience manager

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

I am not able to edit the component in Experience manager, but I can edit in CME.

Also I can edit the page. But when trying to edit the component it shows the following error:

> Editing Disabled: Editing this content has been explicitly disabled
>   for all user.to enable editing this content , contact your sdl
>   Application Administrator.

And refreshing the page sometimes I get the following error message:

> You are not authorized to edit this component: Your System
>   Administrator has not granted you the rights to modify this component.

I am using the System administrator credential to edit this feature.

This is the sample mark up that has been generated from my code.

```
<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="row"> 
            <div class="span4">
               <!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:2033-4796", "ComponentModified" : "2015-10-27T12:10:40", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:2033-4740-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2015-10-22T11:37:35", "IsRepositoryPublished" : true} -->
                <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:header[1]"} -->                      <h2>Ohh God</h2> 
                <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:description[1]"} -->                    <p>god help me</p>

            </div>
        </div>    
   </div>
```

This is my Razor view code:

```
@model DD4T.ContentModel.IComponentPresentation;
@using DD4T.XPM; @using DD4T.Mvc.Html;
<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">              
            @Html.SiteEditComponentPresentation(Model)
            @if (Model.Component.Fields.ContainsKey("write"))
            {
                var field = Model.Component.Fields["write"];
                @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, field)
                  <h2>@field.Value.ToString()</h2> 
            }                
            @if (Model.Component.Fields.ContainsKey("reviewerName"))
            {
                var field = Model.Component.Fields["reviewerName"];
                @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, field)
                <p>@field.Value.ToString()</p>
            }                
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Error while editing component]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not look like valid Experience Manager Markup to me.

The `<!-- Start Component Field -->` HTML comments need to be within a separate block level element in order that XPM can display them properly, so I'd start by fixing that. I'd suggest placing them *inside* the `<h2>` and `<p>` tags, like this:

```
@model DD4T.ContentModel.IComponentPresentation;
@using DD4T.XPM; @using DD4T.Mvc.Html;
<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">              
            @Html.SiteEditComponentPresentation(Model)
            @if (Model.Component.Fields.ContainsKey("write"))
            {
                var field = Model.Component.Fields["write"];
                <h2>
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, field)
                    @field.Value.ToString()
                </h2> 
            }                
            @if (Model.Component.Fields.ContainsKey("reviewerName"))
            {
                var field = Model.Component.Fields["reviewerName"];
                <p>
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, field)
                    @field.Value.ToString()
                </p>
            }                
        </div>
    </div>
```

If that doesn't fully solve the issue, I'd check that the fields were configured as inline editable in the component's schema, like this:

[image: Inline editable setting for Schema fields]

Also check that the Component Template in use has inline editing enabled, like this:

[image: Inline editing setting for Component Template]

Comment: Thanks David. It was the CT where the Enable editing check box was not checked.

Comment: @Manas.p, You should accept David Forster answer if following that your issue got fixed..

Answer (score 3):

Can you double-check your Blueprint Context Settings have been set appropriately as well?  Take a look at this post as well:
[On an Experience Manager website the UI loads but the component is not editable](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/on-an-experience-manager-website-the-ui-loads-but-the-component-is-not-editable?rq=1)

Also documented here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-DB96F4C4-1B66-4D1D-AC29-623CE23DDE38

Comment: I also thought it may be permissions/BluePrint related but discounted it as he states he is accessing as an Administrator. Still worth checking though!